# Render javascript effect of photogallery in cefsharp form

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a problem with cefsharp in render photogallery that inserted in c# form. I use this photogallery:

http://javascript-html5-tutorial.net/2016/02/15/3d-flipping-gallery-with-jquery-and-css3-tutorial-and-example.html

when photos automatically or by click changed, size of photos changed, and dispose effect, it seems that photogallery region at effect moment change to biger window and small window.

[image]

Comment: 1. Does the error occur in a regular Chrome browser also, or _only_ in CefSharp?
2. Would you have a chance to publish your code e.g. in a Gist or in a public GitHub repository? That way, it's easier for me and others to look at it and help finding an answer to your question.

Comment: This javascrip gallery and many js gallery and also all web page with js effect  that I test, have this problem at js effect moment.

Comment: OK. Could you post a screenshot that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I upload screenshot.